# Mysql syntax error when doing a full text serach

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Here is mysql query that I am using for the full-text search:

```
SELECT * FROM subscribers
    WHERE MATCH (full_name,phone,email,company,url,group)
    AGAINST ('samar' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

And here is error that I recieve:

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'group)
    AGAINST ('database' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, `group` is a reserved keyword.  If you actually named a column after this (you shouldn't have), then you can avoid this error by escaping it:

```
SELECT * FROM subscribers
WHERE MATCH (`full_name`, `phone`, `email`, `company`, `url`, `group`)
AGAINST ('samar' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

I escaped every column in my answer because it looks consistent, but I believe you should only need to escape `group`.

Comment: Thanks, i missed that group is a reserved keyword.